# Postsharp: ThreadAffineAttribute and async method

Tags: postsharp

This method throws error: `An attempt was made to access the object from an invalid thread.`

If I were removed `Task.Delay` then it would work.

But I need async methods to work.

```
public async Task<int> Test() {
    await Task.Delay( 100 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, according to your comments, you don't need your object to be thread-affined, but instead need to make sure it's only accessed by one thread at any given moment, you may consider using the Actor threading model instead (https://doc.postsharp.net/actor).

Another threading model that may work for you is Synchronized (https://doc.postsharp.net/synchronized), which is basically an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `async` thread-affine types, then they can only be called from single-threaded contexts, e.g., a UI context or [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

However, it's extremely rare to need `async` on a thread-affine type. I'd reconsider the thread-affinity requirement.

Comment: I just want to be sure that my object is used only by one thread. It's not problem that some methods are async. But it's problem for ThreadAffineAttribute.

Comment: @wishmaster35: "Thread affine" means that there's something particular about that object that ties it to a specific thread. It does not mean "one thread at a time".

Comment: `It does not mean "one thread at a time"` I understand it. I say again: I need async methods to work. What is problem?

Comment: Thread-affine means that *all* the code for that type *must* always run on the *same* thread - the same thread it was created on.

Comment: Okey. So I need something else.